# jQuery UI Show/Hide behave different than jQuery show/hide? Maybe a bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What I’m trying to do, is a simple toolbar that shows/Hide when I mouseover/mouseleave over to parent.
It’s a little bit hard and long to explain, so I did a sample of the problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ppr4N/44/

The box on the top works the way I want. I use .show(300) and .hide(300) I think this are the regular methods from jQuery.

On the bottom box, I use .show(“slide”) and .hide(“slide”), I think this methods are extended by the UI.
The problem is that when I move the mouse over the “Bump”, the toolbox hides and shows like a maniac.

By the Way! I'm using UI 1.8.10 and jQuery 1.5.1, (both from MS CND) I also tried with a couple of old versions and the result is the same.

Any Idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Edgar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".container2")
        .unbind()
        .hover(
            function () {
                $(".toolbar2").show('slide',300);
            },
            function () {
                 $(".toolbar2").hide('slide',300);
            });
```

I don't know why mouseOver was being called multiple times, but it doesn't have this problem using .hover().

Answer (score 0):

It's just because mouseover gets called multiple times. You can wrap your call to `.show("slide")` in `if (!$(this).find(".toolbar2").is(":visible")) {`, so that it will only ever run once. That will fix the problem. Probably do the inverse check on your hide.

Alternatively, use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. That will only be run once, although I've seen some odd behaviour with this on IE6 previously.